# idiv overflow exception asm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm very new to assembly, before only C C++
I was trying to create a simple application that print all the prime number from 2 to given input
When I run, it crashes, and that's normal. Looking at OllyDbg, the guilty piece is this:

```
move eax, ebx
idiv ecx ; !!! here
```

It is strange because ecx is not 0 
 Values are EAX = 0000 0004, ECX = 0000 0002, and it says me that's an Integer_Overflow (exception C000 0095)
How it's possible to have an **overflow** during a division? Both operands are 32bit

Floowing the code and a screenshot of ollydbg

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
input_msg   db  "Insert a number: ", 0
output_msg  db  "This is prime: ", 0

segment .bss
input       resd    1

segment .text
global _asm_main

; input => input number
; ebx => current number to execute [2 .. input]
; ecx => counter from 2 to current [2 .. current]

_asm_main:
    mov eax, input_msg
    call print_string

    call read_int
    inc eax
    mov [input], eax
    call print_nl

    mov ebx, 2h

    _start_main_loop:
        mov eax, [input] ; if current > input
        cmp eax, ebx
        jz _end_main_loop       

        mov ecx, 2h

        _iteration:
            cmp ebx, ecx
            je _print_number

            mov eax, ebx
            idiv ecx ; unsigned division?

            cmp edx, 0 ; if rem != 0 jmp
            jne _end_iteration
            inc ecx ; else inc ecx and re-divide
            jmp _iteration

        _print_number:
            mov eax, output_msg
            call print_string
            mov eax, ebx
            call print_int
            call print_nl

        _end_iteration:
            inc ebx

            jmp _start_main_loop

    _end_main_loop:

    popa
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

[image]

Comment: You completely overlooked that idiv divides edx:eax by ecx.  You need to add CDQ to sign-extend eax into edx.

Comment: The same error happens if I use unsigned div. It's more strange. But now with xor/cdq it seems to work

Comment: If you use div then you don't care about sign-extension and treat the operands as unsigned numbers.  Just zero edx with xor edx,edx and do *not* use cdq.

Comment: Can someone tell me why people voted -1 a lawful, already answered question?

Comment: ARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRDUINO! I LIKE IT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer overflow exception on `idiv` instruction occurs when result of n-bit division can not fit into n-bit register. That is possible because `idiv` and `div` divide the whole register pair `EDX:EAX`. Your `EDX` value is 1 and you divide `EDX:EAX` by 2, which results into a bit shift to right. This shift moves `1` on `EAX`´s MSB, and you have a positive result `0x80000000` greather than `0x7FFFFFFF`, what is illegal according to the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZt7P.png).

You may be asking yourself "why is there such restriction?". It's there, because a negative value (MSB set) in `EAX` wouldn't be a valid result of division of two positive integers.

A general solution for this problem is either to zero contents of `EDX` before unsigned division

```
mov eax, ebx
xor edx, edx
div ecx ;unsigned division
```

...or to sign-extend EAX (if you expect negative input, which you shouldn't beacuse no negative integer can be a prime number).

```
mov eax, ebx
cdq 
idiv ecx ;signed division
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Just another little tiny question: when I run the program, now with cdq, it says 'access violation when reading'. Could it be still the 'div' istruction? Shouldn't be because you don't read during a div, but before this question, in my opinion, div didn't generate overlows. However, it's possible in your opinion?

Comment: It is possible if you use EDX somewhere else for accessing memory.

Comment: I don't. But I use the library of drpaulcarter's pcasm. Could it be the problem?

Comment: You've got OllyDbg, try to find out. OllyDbg will also tell you where exactly it occurs.